# prevent sql injection in Go with fmt.Sprintf for native query

Tags: database, go, prepared-statement, sql-injection

is this query make sql injection or bad for query insert statement

```
    query := fmt.Sprintf("INSERT INTO users(%s) VALUES(%s) RETURNING user_id, otp",
        repo.getColumns(), // returning users columns
        repo.setValues(), // looping to create $1, $2 (depent length of users columns)
    )
    stmt, err := db.Prepare(query)
    checkError(err)
    defer func() {
        if err = stmt.Close(); err != nil {
            panic(err.Error())
        }
    }()
    err = stmt.QueryRowContext(ctx,
        user.Email,
        user.CardID,
        user.CardFee,
        user.PhoneNumber,
        user.Gender,
        user.BirthDate,
        user.BirthCityID,
        user.Education,
        user.MotherName,
        user.MotherPhone,
        user.PartnerPhone,
        user.FamilyCardNumber,
        user.Religion,
        user.CitizenShip,
        user.MaritalStatus,
        user.SpouseCardID,
        user.SpouseFullName,
        user.SpouseBirthDate,
    ).Scan(&userData.ID, &userData.CardID)
```

here `repo.getColumns()` is a method which return string of **users columns** and `setValues()` is a string manipulation to create $1, $2, .... from the length of users column on method `getColumns()`
will it potential security ?? alos on the QueryRowContext parameter second and so .... it is `...interface{}` and if i have a lot of columns, i shoudl input manual one by one, is that something to make it shorter ?

Comment: Yes, there's potential for SQL injection. How serious the vulnerability is, however depends on the trustworthiness of the data being interpolated into the query string.

Comment: how to correct way and good to write query? for my case @mkopriva

Answer (score -1):

The possibility for an sql injection attack lies in the values returned by the function calls `repo.getColumns()` and `repo.setValues()`.

The question is how much control do you have over what those functions return? Is their behaviour based on user input? If so, then you could for instance protect yourself against injection attacks by doing some simple pattern maching - for instance, if you expect a name, check that the input consists of only letters and spaces.

You could also try to exclude any special signs that can be used for an injection attack and are not expected as part of the column names of values.

> ... if i have a lot of columns, i shoudl input manual one by one, is that something to make it shorter ?

I suggest asking a separate question about this, as it is a distinct problem.